# How to display everyone of the label and the radio choices in its own line?

Tags: forms, struts2, radio-button, label

I'm using Struts2. By default, when using the struts form, the label and the choices are displayed in the same line. **How can I do to make the label in a line, and every radio choice in its own line?** Is there a way by CSS? I need your help guys. Here it is how my form looks like. Thank you!

```
<s:form action="resultAction" namespace="/"> 
  <s:radio label="Gender" name="yourGender" list="genders" value="defaultGenderValue" />  
  <s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which theme are you using as by default struts2 use xHtml theme and which generate certain set of Tables to render the view.
Struts2 use free-marker template to render the HTML for tags and you can customize theme as per your choice or can create you rown theme.

Try with simple theme which will not generate any table or div and will render plain HTML for you are you have all way to apply your custom CSS to change/customize the view.

You can set the theme per page basis on for the whole application for per page basis add the following line in the head section

```
<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />
```

for whole application you can either set in struts.properties file or in struts.xml file though the second one is more preferable.

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

If you want to play with theme here is the link for same

- [struts-2-themes](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-themes.html)

Comment: Of you can set the theme just for the radio element: `<s:radio label="Gender" name="yourGender" list="genders" value="defaultGenderValue" theme="simple"/>`